# Calling web service error in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm facing a weird behavior in my IOs application, let me comment you a bit about it:

### General method called from the UI

```
func GetSensorList(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
        self.sensors = Sensor.GenerateSensorList()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

I have this method that call a rest Web Service:

```
static func GenerateSensorList() -> [Sensor]{
    var sensores = [Sensor]()
    let manager: AppManager = AppManager.manager
    var userData: UserData? = nil
    do{
        userData = try manager.GetUserData()
        if let userDataAux = userData {
            manager.SaveSharedUserData(userDataAux)
            if(userDataAux.weatherSettings!.weatherCity != nil){
                var unit = "imperial"
                if(userDataAux.weatherSettings!.tempFormat! == "C"){
                    unit = "metric"
                }
                let s = userDataAux.weatherSettings!.weatherCity!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "@")
                let weather = try manager.GetWeatherData(s, metric: unit)
                let temperatureInt = Int(weather.weatherMain!.temp!)
                let description = weather.weatherItem![0].description
                let temp = "Temp: " +  String(temperatureInt) + "°" + (userData!.weatherSettings!.tempFormat!)
                let sensorAux = Sensor(image: weather.image, label1: description , label2:temp)
                    sensores.append(sensorAux)

            }
        }
        let deviceData = try? manager.RetrieveDeviceDataObject()
        if(deviceData != nil){
            if(deviceData!?.DeviceDataItems != nil){
                let deviceDataItems = deviceData!?.DeviceDataItems!
                for(var i = 0; i < deviceDataItems?.count; i++){
                    let catId = deviceDataItems![i].CategoryId
                    let devId = deviceDataItems![i].DeviceItemId
                    switch catId!{
                    case 12: break
                    case 16:
                        let devItem = try manager.GetDeviceHumiditySensorItemById(devId!)
                        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "ic_devices")!
                        var humidityValue = ""
                        if(devItem.DeviceItemHumiditySensorHumidity != nil){
                            humidityValue = (devItem.DeviceItemHumiditySensorHumidity)!
                        }else{
                            humidityValue = "0"
                        }
                        let sensorAux = Sensor(image: photo1, label1: devItem.DeviceItemName , label2: ( humidityValue + "%"))
                        sensores.append(sensorAux)
                    case 17:
                        let devItem = try manager.GetDeviceTemperatureSensorItemById(devId!)
                        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "ic_devices")!
                        let sensorAux = Sensor(image: photo1, label1: devItem.DeviceItemName , label2: ((devItem.DeviceItemTemperatureSensorTemperature)! + "°" + (userData!.weatherSettings!.tempFormat!)))
                        sensores.append(sensorAux)
                    case 18:
                        let devItem = try manager.GetDeviceLightSensorItemById(devId!)
                        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "ic_devices")!
                        let sensorAux = Sensor(image: photo1, label1: devItem.DeviceItemName , label2: ((devItem.DeviceItemLightSensorLight)!))
                        sensores.append(sensorAux)
                    case 21:
                        let devItem = try manager.GetDevicePowerMeterItemById(devId!)
                        let photo1 = UIImage(named: "ic_devices")!
                        let sensorAux = Sensor(image: photo1, label1: devItem.DeviceItemName , label2: ((devItem.DeviceItemPowerMeterWatts)! + "Watts"))
                        sensores.append(sensorAux)
                    default: break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch{
        sensores = [Sensor]()
    }
    return sensores
}
```

In the line:

`let weather = try manager.GetWeatherData(s, metric: unit)`

I face the following issue: When I'm using the iPad emulator the method works fine, but when I'm using an iPhone 6 emulator I found that the data is different and the application crash.

I checked and the iPhone and the iPad is running the same version of IOs (9.2), the url is exactly the same, but the NSDATA object that I got are different.

### GetWeatherData code:

```
func GetWeatherData(cityName: String, metric: String) throws -> WeatherCondition{
    do{
        var weather = WeatherCondition()
        let url = SERVICEURL + "/GetWeather/" + cityName + "/" + metric
        let data = try ExecuteRequestServiceHeader(url, mmsAuth: nil, mmsAuthSig: nil, mmsSession: nil)
        if let dataAux = data{
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataAux, options: .MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
            let jsonleave = json["GetWeatherResult"] as? String
            if let jsonLeaveAux = jsonleave{
                weather = WeatherCondition.JsonToObject(jsonLeaveAux)
                let iconVar = weather.weatherItem![0].icon
                let urlIcon = SERVICEURL + "/GetWeatherIcon/"+iconVar!
                let dataIcon = try ExecuteRequestService(urlIcon)
                if let dataIconAux = dataIcon{
                    let jsonIcon = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataIconAux, options: .MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
                    if let jsonleaveIcon = jsonIcon["GetWeatherIconResult"] as? NSArray{
                        var byteArray = [UInt8]()
                        for (var i = 0; i < jsonleaveIcon.count; i++){
                            byteArray.append(UInt8(String(jsonleaveIcon[i]))!)
                        }
                        let imData = NSData(bytes: byteArray, length: (byteArray.count))
                        let image = UIImage(data: imData)
                        weather.image = image
                    }
                }else{
                    throw AppManagerError.ErrorAccessingService(url: "Getting Weather data")
                }
            }else{
                throw AppManagerError.ErrorAccessingService(url: "Getting Weather data")
            }
        }else{
            throw AppManagerError.ErrorAccessingService(url: "Getting Weather data")
        }
        return weather
    }catch{
        throw AppManagerError.ErrorAccessingService(url: "Getting Weather data")
    }
}
```

The application throw an exception in this line:

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataAux, options: .MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
```

Exception Track:

> caught: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not
>   start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I will appreciate any help on this

Comment: Could you include a stack trace or the text of the exception you get for JSONObjectWithData call...

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I don't get any problem in the stack trace and the exception it is because the NSDATA object that I'm getting can't be serialized. And that's why I don't understand why with the iPhone the data is different from the iPad data.

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera Please print the error which will be caught in the final `catch` clause. Currently, you just re-throw the error.  What's also strange in your code is, that despite network calls are inherently asynchronous - your code seems to be employ a synchronous style. That might not work seamlessly and will block threads.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper, I added the main method, sorry but I don't know how to print the the exception, could give me a tip please, so I could share with you the exception description

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thanks for your comment, I added the stack trace.

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera - related to printing the exception, the easiest thing to do is something like this: catch(let e) {print(e)}

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thanks, I did it and I posted the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was getting to complicated to write in a comment, so I will put this in answers.

First off, I am a bit confused by this part of your code:

```
 do{
    var weather = WeatherCondition()
    let url = SERVICEURL + "/GetWeather/" + cityName + "/" + metric
    let data = try ExecuteRequestServiceHeader(url, mmsAuth: nil, mmsAuthSig: nil, mmsSession: nil)
    if let dataAux = data{
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataAux, options: .MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary
```

You look like are you trying to create the dataAux variable based on trying to serialize dataAux **not** data. I would assume you want to call the JSONObjectWithData method on data. Not sure why you would see a difference on the different platforms, but that could be part of the problem.

In addition, it is worth calling the JSONObjectWithData method using .AllowFragments to see if this helps. I would also suggest taking doing something like this to see what the data actually looks like before you try to serialize it. At the very least it might help you trouble shoot the difference between the two platforms.

```
print(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do what you suggest me and I'll let you know.

Comment: spottedrabbit I found an error, when I'm using an iPhone the web service is returning "Runtime error" in html format, that's why I got the exception trying to parsing to JSON. But the weird is that when I'm using the iPad this work fine.

Comment: No probs. Gland I got you pointed in the right direction. Good luck sorting out the underlying issue with the webservice.